# Why does "and" operator on two values give the last value?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I've been tinkering a little with Python operators and came across something I'm not sure about.

If I perform a bitwise operation (`&`, `|`) on 2 integers I will get unsurprisingly their bitwise value.
Meaning:

```
>>> a = 11
>>> b = 3
>>> a & b
3
```

This is because it performs bitwise AND on the binary representation of these numbers.

However, if I use the built in `and` operator I will get the second variable, irrespective of its type:

```
>>> b and a
11
>>> 'b' and 'a'
'a'
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Why? Because this is how the `and` operator is defined.

Comment: `and` is a logical operator, not bitwise.

Comment: Nope you get the first operand that decides the expression's truth value.

Comment: It gives the second value *when the first value is true*. (Note that "being true" does not require an object to be the specific object `True`.)

Comment: Some test cases you can experiment with... `False and True`, `False and False`, `True and True`, `True and False`. Run each of these and the reason will become apparent. You can replace `False` and `True` with any falsey or truthy value, respectively.

Comment: Also `False and 'a'`, `'a' and False`, `True and 'a'`, `'a' and True`.

Comment: I suggest you read more about "truthiness", "falsiness" and the logical operators.

Comment: Related: [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](/q/39983695/4518341), [Does Python support short-circuiting?](/q/2580136/4518341)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logical operators operate on the *truthiness* of an object. Every object has truth value, unless it has a [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method that is explicitly overridden to raise an error. The major difference between `a and b` (logical) and `a & b` (bitwise) is that the former apply to any objects, while the latter only apply to numeric types that support bitwise operations<sup>1</sup>.

Python's logical operators are specifically designed to return the result of the last object evaluated:

- `a and b`: Returns a Falsy `a`, or `b` (if `a` is truthy)
- `a or b`: Returns a Truthy `a`, or `b` (if `a` if falsy)

From the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> The Boolean operators `and` and `or` are so-called short-circuit operators: their arguments are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the outcome is determined. For example, if `A` and `C` are true but `B` is false, `A and B and C` does not evaluate the expression `C`. When used as a general value and not as a Boolean, the return value of a short-circuit operator is the last evaluated argument.

This property is used semi-idiomatically to check values before accessing them. For example, if a list must contain an element, you can do something like

```
if x and x[0] == value:
    # ...
```

This will not raise an error, because if `x` is Falsy (empty), the `and` expression will return `x` instead of `x[0] == value`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Set-like objects also support `&` as the intersection operator. This is conceptually similar to what the bitwise operator does for integers (you can think of bits as sets), and in no way detracts from the rest of the answer.

Comment: Many types lack a `__bool__` method. If `__bool__` is missing, a non-zero return value from `__len__` indicates truthiness. If `__len__` is also missing, the object is considered truthy. (For example, `list` defines `__len__` but not `__bool__`, and `object` defines neither.)

Comment: @chepner. Sorry, hasty phrasing. Fixed now

Comment: No problem. I think I'll leave the comment, if only because I'm not sure it's worth delving into the whole `__len__`-vs-`__bool__` issue in the answer itself.

Comment: @chepner. Thanks. It does enhance the answer.

Comment: Nitpicking, but `&` isn't only defined for numeric types, it's also defined for set-like types like `set` (ofc) and dict keys, as well as NumPy array and Pandas Series/DataFrame.

Comment: @wjandrea. Good call. I added a footnote.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) says:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Since Python considers the boolean value for both strings and non-zero integers to be `True`, `x and y` would imply `True and True`, and since the boolean of the first statement is not False, the second statement is evaluated and the resulting value (which is the value of the second term) is returned.

Comment: You probably should have said "non-empty strings" because `""` is considered False.

Answer (score 2):

The first case with `and`:

```py
>>> b and a #(11 and 3, both the values evaluates to be true because non-zero)
11
>>> 'b' and  'a' #(again both are evaluated to be true because non-empty)
```

For `and` all the conditions need to be `True`, so checked upto the last item if the previous evaluates to be `True`, hence you get the last  item.

Comment: The relationship between `bool` and `int` doesn't actually matter here.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, thanks for the comment, I realized a bit later. For this specific case, that doessn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 : A **and** B
here consider A ,B both are non zeroes for and it checks both A,B that is it first evaluates A if in A after conversion in binary(for understanding consider positive integers , A > 0 and B > 0) whether 1 is present or not , if yes it moves to B and returns B as output. Because **and** checks both A and B.

A **or** B

here it checks the  A as same as above if it has 1 after converting in to binary,
if A is True it return A  (obviously A > 0 so it return A only ).

case 2 : suppose Any 1 in A,B or both A,B are **ZEROES**
I will try to explain in better way . I hope we all know truth tables for **'AND'** and **'OR'** and **'XOR'**.
Same thing happening here just replace **1's and 0's** with any number,  if you want you use *only 1's and 0's to understand in better way*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).